# How to prepare fingerprint images as input for CNN?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, fingerprint

I use the [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) algorithm to extract features from a fingerprint image dataset, and I would like to use the [VGG16](https://neurohive.io/en/popular-networks/vgg16/) convolutional neural network (CNN) architecture for fingerprint recognition.

Is there a function to convert the fingerprint features to an array of vectors or pixels to use as input for the CNN?

Answer (score 1):

The VGG16 CNN architecture is designed to receive whole images as input. As any artificial neural network, it is expected to perform the feature extraction automatically, within the first few layers. So in this sense, the CNN is an *alternative* to the SIFT algorithm for fingerprint recognition. You could feed the same images you used as input to SIFT directly to the CNN and compare their performances.

However, it is possible that if you combine SIFT and the CNN in some clever way, the performance will be even better. There is no simple answer to how best to do that, because this is an ongoing area of research. See, for example, this paper:

> Z. Zhou, Q. M. J. Wu, S. Wan, W. Sun and X. Sun, "Integrating SIFT and CNN Feature Matching for Partial-Duplicate Image Detection," in IEEE Transactions on Emerging Topics in Computational Intelligence, vol. 4, no. 5, pp. 593-604, Oct. 2020, doi: [10.1109/TETCI.2019.2909936](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9121754).